# SELECT TWO TIMES (minutes) that fall across midnight

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select registers from a date between a time (23:00 to 02:00, for example), but I dont know how to elaborate a select for that case.

I have two fields (integer value) and only one field for date. 
The date field dont record the timestamp, its the application that I use that do that, and there is nothing to do about it. The time is recorded in two fields ("start time" and "end time"), and, sometimes the "end time" cross over midnight.

```
date                | start time | end time
16-08-2016 00:00:00 | 1420       | 90
```

The time is in minutes, so, `start time` is `23:40` and `end time` is `01:30`.

My select is starting to get bigger and I'm afraid that what I'm doing is wrong.

EDIT - Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (((1320 >= StartTime OR 1320 <= EndTime) AND EndTime < StartTime AND MyDate <= '17/08/2016') OR
         ((1350 >= StartTime OR 1350 <= EndTime) AND EndTime < StarTime AND MyDate <= '17/08/2016'))
```

Comment: Please post your query and actually ask a coherent question.

Comment: Edited my post with the query. Sorry for my bad english, really sorry

Comment: I need to compare a "range" with that table. Its something like "i need to get all the registers that are from 22:00 to 22:30". But, I dont know that to do when I need to get from 23:45 to 00:15

Comment: Oracle does not have "dates" and "times", it only has a "date" data type which **always** includes a time-of-day component (which may be 00:00 if you only show hours and minutes). Do you have an actual table in the database, with the date shown separately, and the start time and end time shown as numbers? What does 90 mean as an end time?

Comment: Thats because of the application, not the database. The aplication that runs the bd do all those things about "one field" to date (without the time, so, its 00:00 always) and two integer fields.

Comment: OK, I think I understand... so these are your inputs; 1420 is 1420 minutes = 23 hours + 40 minutes... and if end time is < start time (and only then) it is on the next day (and not four days later, for example). Good. Now, what is your requirement? Do you need to select some of the rows from this table? What was the rule again? What is given to you - the start (date + time) and the end (date + time), and you need to find all the rows with the time interval in the row contained in this "outside-given" range? Or what?

Comment: I see your comment above. What do you mean by "registers that are from 22:00 to 22:30"? What is a "register"?

Comment: "register" = "row" @mathguy, sorry, im really bad when trying to write in english without revise what I wrote. And about your question, you are right. I think that maybe I im waking in the right way to solve this, if you see this print: prntscr.com/c7gxs0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fields you have to calculate the start and end points as Oracle `DATE`s (which include both date and time).  Then filter as for any other `DATE` columns.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
-- This inline view gets everything in your table, plus the start_datetime and end_datetime as calculated from your various fields.
SELECT your_table.*, start_date + ( start_time / 1440 ) start_datetime, start_date + case when end_time < start_time then end_time + 1440 else end_time end end_datetime FROM your_table
) 
WHERE start_datetime between ... whatever date range you want ...
AND end_datetime between ... whatever date range you want ...
```

Comment: Gonna try later. Thanks. EDIT: IT WORKED. Now im going to implement this in my queries. Your ideia come to me did this: http://prntscr.com/c7gxs0 I DONT KNOW if it can be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select date, starttime, DATEADD(mi, endtime,Dateadd(mi,starttime, cast(date     as datetime))) AS Enddatetime
   FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Hi there. I see that you're fairly new to answering questions on SO. Here is a link that will help you make your posts more readable: [How do I format my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). But in short, if you want to format code (like SQL), just indent the code block 4 spaces to the right. Alternatively, if you select the code block, there is then a very convenient button/icon in the editor ({}) that you can click on that will perform the indentation for you.

Comment: remember that my starttime is in minutes (integer) and not date. It will rowk anyway?

Comment: I tested this using `create table question
(
startdate date,
starttime int,
endtime int
)`

Comment: I did everything that you said @Oops_U_broke_it but it says ORA-00902. (sorry for the delay). http://prntscr.com/c7grgk

Answer (score 1):

I've put what you're looking for within variables at the top so you only have to enter them once.  You can embed them in the query along with the conversion logic, but it's messy.

```
declare @date datetime, @start int, @end int
select @date = '17/8/2016', @start = 1425, @end = 15

-- convert minutes past midnight
select @end = @end + case when @start > @end then 1440 else 0 end

select  *
from    Table
where   MyDate = @date
    and StartTime between @start and @end
    and EndTime + case when StartTime > EndTime then 1440 else 0 end between @start and @end
```

This finds all registers that started and ended within the specified times.  Use the below where clause if you also need to find ones that ran during the times but either started before, finished after, or both.

```
where   MyDate = @date
    and StartTime < @end
    and EndTime + case when StartTime > EndTime then 1440 else 0 end > @start
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server syntax. But OP is using Oracle.

Comment: Yes, im using oracle. Gonna try what you did

Comment: Its not going to work because my ``StartTime`` from the ``Table`` is 0 (integer) when it is in the day 18/8/2016 and the select MUST bring the register that you declared. As the @start is 1425 and the @end is 15+1440, then, it will not bring this register.